# What does “hit the same beats as it did” mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> Mick Jagger is sitting on a sofa wearing a pale grey fleece and talking about Charlie Watts. The drummer first played with the Rolling Stones in early 1963, after they had tried six months with a different man. Watts was at every gig they played until he died last August, aged 80. One month later the band were back on stage in the US, in St Louis, and **the set list hit the same beats as it did the last time Watts played.**  Rock through Start Me Up, roll into Paint It Black, end with (I Can’t Get No) Satisfaction. Except Watts was not there. And Jagger missed him.

Hello everyone. I need some help. What does the sentence in bold above mean? Does it mean that  the band played the same songs as they did the last time with Watts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it means that the band played the same songs as they did the last time with Watts.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Michael Harvey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of **hit the same beats**, you can say:

> **had the same songs**

It's not a particularly common way of saying this, but the writer is trying to be clever with words in a story about a drummer.

Comment: Thank you so much  for the explanation.